# How to customise a date in excel

Tags: excel, date, formatting

I am using the following function

```
=TODAY()
```

After changing the formatting using the 'Format Cells', I get this

```
04 November 2022
```

Is there a way to change it such that only the first three characters of the month are shown and only the last two digits of the year are shown ie

```
04 Nov 22
```

Comment: Custom format as `dd mmm yy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the format shown, type your function =TODAY(), select the cell that is showing the date, at the top select Home tab and then in "Number" select "Number Format" and go to the last option "More Number Formats...", then when a "Format Cells"windows appears, select "Number" and then "Data", and you can select your preference format.

OR

Press CTRL + 1 and select Date.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/available-number-formats-in-excel-0afe8f52-97db-41f1-b972-4b46e9f1e8d2